# Is there any linear isomoprhism between $X'$ and $Y'$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, and $T: X\rightarrow Y$ be an linear isomorphism. Is there any linear isomoprhism between $X'$ and $Y'$?

Any help?

Comment: Do you see a natural candidate for an isomorphism $S \colon Y' \to X'$?

Comment: Unfortunately, not.

Comment: Any linear map $Y'\to X'$?

Comment: $T^*(a)=aT$, $a\in Y'$ ?

Comment: By $aT$, you mean the composition? So the transpose/dual/adjoint of $T$. Yes.

Comment: Yes, composition

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help if you dropped the extraneous assumptions.

Try to show the following: the dual is a (contravariant) functor, that is, for any linear mapping $f\colon X\to Y$, you have a canonical choice of a mapping $f'\colon Y'\to X'$, in such a way that:

1. For any $X$ and identity $\operatorname{id}_X\colon X\to X$ you have $\operatorname{id}_{X'}=(\operatorname{id}_X)'\colon X'\to X'$.
2. For any $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$ you have $(g\circ f)'=f'\circ g'$.

Then apply this to your isomorphism.